# USB Device Causing VM's to Freeze

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, freeze, vmware-workstation

USB Device Causing VM's to Freeze - Cannot Kill vmware-vmx.exe

The problem was described here - https://communities.vmware.com/thread/612551
but anyone has no answer for it.

Generally, the problem is like so:

1. launch vm
2. connect usb stick or usb phone cable
3. vm freezes
4. it is not possible to terminate vmware-vmx.exe process (even as a SYSTEM user with highest privs).

The issue occurs on vmware workstation 14 & 15 on Windows 10 Pro Build 1903
Also tried disabling windows defender (maybe some strange scan policy) but no results.
Tried also to change almost every setting in workstation but no results...

please help

Comment: Is VMware Tools installed? Maybe you're running multiple VMs at the same time. please check this thread: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/290056           In addition, in your workstation status bar, click your relative usb to connect, also make sure if in your vm settings, the usb is set to usb 2.0 or 3.0, then connect it to the corresponding one.

Comment: thank you. USB 2.0 is a partial fix, however sometimes even if vm tools are installed copy&paste operations between host and guest make vm unresponsive and vmware-vmx.exe freezed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same issue and I have finally found the solution. 
Update to VMWare Workstation version 15.5. Update the VM Tools in the Guest operating System, and it works!! Tried with Android Devices, in USB Tethering Mode also.